# I have lost SQL Server 2008 database, I need to the database structure back from LINQ schema

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008

My SQL Server 2008 server database for one of my new projects has deleted accidentally. What I'm left with is LINQ to SQL schema file (DataContext schema and classes) and with hope to get my database structure back from this.

Is there a way?

Comment: L2S doesn't support going both ways. So, you cannot create a physical database from a .DBML. Why don't you have a backup to restore from?

Comment: Very sad. That must have been some accident.Don't you you create your database from scripts?

Comment: @randy - you mean except for CreateDatabase which attempts to do **exactly** this?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments and especially Marc. I have got my schema back. Luckily project was in the initial stage so database contained only test data, which was no more important than the rich database structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For simple schema you can just call dataContext.CreateDatabase() - however it would be ambitious to hope for this to handle everything. I suspect you may have to accept the loss and (sadly) learn about the value of backups.

See MSDN for more on CreateDatabase:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.createdatabase.aspx

Comment: Thanks Marc, data wasn't important and I got it back using dataContext.CreateDatabase() function.

Answer (score 1):

[DataContext.CreateDatabase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.createdatabase.aspx)

Watch out for missing indexes, lookup data, etc.