# I need to the database structure back from LINQ schema

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I have lost SQL Server 2008 database, I need to the database structure back from LINQ schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412057/i-have-lost-sql-server-2008-database-i-need-to-the-database-structure-back-from)

My SQL Server 2008 server database for one of my new projects has deleted accidentally. What I'm left with is LINQ to SQL schema file (DataContext schema and classes) and with hope to get my database structure back from this.

Is there a way?